# ClojureScript cljsbuild doesn't load dependencies without optimisations

Tags: leiningen, google-closure-compiler, clojurescript, figwheel

I am trying to use figwheel in my ClojureScript build.

It works with `lein cljsbuild auto` already, but I have to put `:optimisations :whitespace`.

Otherwise I get a message in the browser :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: goog is not defined
```

However figwheel require `:optimisations :none` to run. Here is the part of my `leiningen` file :

```
:cljsbuild {
          :builds
          [{:id "dev"
            :source-paths ["src/cljs"]

            :figwheel { :websocket-host "localhost"
                       ;;:on-jsload "example.core/fig-reload"
                       :autoload true
                       :heads-up-display true
                       :load-warninged-code true
                       ;;:url-rewriter "example.core/fig-url-rewrite"
                       }

            :compiler {;; :main
                       :output-to  "resources/public/js/gdb/gdb.js"
                       :output-dir "resources/public/js/gdb/cljsbuild-dev"
                       ;;:asset-path "js/out"

                       :optimizations :none
                       :source-map "resources/public/js/gdb/gdb.js.map"
                       :pretty-print true}}]}
```

What is missing for me to get the missing dependencies ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out this is a classic case of RTFM.
The answer was in the [ClojureScript quickstart](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start) guide.

Specifically, I had to add a `:main` field, as specified in the [Less Boilerplate](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start#less-boilerplate) section :

```
:main "example.core"
```

Comment: FYI: This single comment saved me about 5 hours of suffering. Thanks x 10 for putting it up even after you had already solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing jumps out as being obviously wrong or missing. However, lein is pretty powerful in the degree it lets you set things to fit your personal taste/workflow, so it is hard to spot things if the approach is signficantly different.

When I run into these types of problems, I find using the standard templates provided by many libraries or projects really useful. My recommendation would be to run

```
lein new figwheel ft -- --reagent
```

This will setup a basic project called ft (in this case also with reagent - there is another option for om or you could leave all of this out for a bare bones default. See the figwheel repo on github for more details. This will provide a good working lein figwheel setup which hyou can use as a guide.